# Regex to match all text on multiple lines unless it contains a specific string?

Tags: regex

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the previous responses have worked for me. I have a PDF that I'm trying to convert in Calibre. In the conversion process, I want to get rid of the headers and footers, which look like these:

```
<hr/>
<a name=9></a>viii<br>
<i>Introduction</i><br>

<hr/>
<a name=10></a><i>Introduction</i><br>
ix<br>
```

I used the following regex, which worked beautifully to select all of these instances:

```
(?s)<hr/>(.*?)</a>(.*?)<br>(.*?)<br>
```

HOWEVER, when there is a chapter title, the PDF code says this:

```
<hr/>
<a name=8></a><a href="index.html#6">INTRODUCTION</a><br>
```

which is also picked up by my regex. I want to alter my code to ignore the chapter titles. I have tried dozens of combinations replacing the

```
(.*?)
```

with things like

```
[^index] 
^((?!index).)*$ 
/(?s)^((?!index).)*$/
```

I have also tried each of these with href, =, and " instead of "index," but none of these codes pick up *anything.* Any ideas what I need to change in my code so I can remove the headers and footers without removing the chapter titles? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ok, I solved my problem by cheating. I opened the pdf in Adobe Acrobat, cropped the headers out of the pages, and deleted the hidden data. However, if anybody know of a way I could have made this work with regex, I'd love to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not all that hard. Assuming that your HTML is always simple and doesn't contain anything tricky like `<` or `>` in quotes, just add this:

```
(?:<a[^>]+href=[^>]+>.*?</a>)?
```

immediately after the `</a>` in your current regex. That bit says that the header may or may not be there, and either way, don't pick it up (the noncapturing group, `(?:)`.)